# Pass button value as variable of an upload file

Tags: javascript

I am quite new to javascript and i need some guidance. I have a table that displays some data, the source code of the table is this.

```
function user_clients_table_storagefolder() {

   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",'');
   if(!$con){

   die("Cannot Connect" . mysql_error());

   }
    mysql_select_db("client_app",$con);
    $get_user_clients = "SELECT `ID`,`Name`,`SurName`,`storagefolder` FROM `clients`  ";
   $clients = mysql_query($get_user_clients,$con);

   echo "<table class=table table-condensed>
   <thead>
   <tr>   
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>SurName</th>
   <th>Recipient</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>";
   while($record = mysql_fetch_array($clients)){
    echo "<action=pushnotification.php method=post>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$record['ID']." </td>";
    echo "<td>".$record['Name']." </td>";
    echo "<td>".$record['SurName']." </td>";
    echo "<td>"."<button type=button id=contact class=btn btn-primary  value=".$record['Name'].">Primary</button></td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";

     }

echo "</table>";     
mysql_close();


//function that is used to display the table of all the clients and fetch back the storagefolder of each user
}
```

Every table row has a button in the last column that has a different value. When i click any of the buttons a pop up form is displayed asking to upload a file. The source code of the form is the following:

```
<div id="contactForm">
  <p><h4><font color="white"><i>First Choose the clients and then the file which will be uploaded in order to proced</i></font></h4></2>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <input type="file" class="upload" name="onstorage" id="upload_file" size="50" name="icon" onchange="loadFile(this);" >
    <hr>
      <div id="myProgress">
        <div id="myBar"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

The code that launches the pop up is the following:

```
<script>
$(function() {

  // contact form animations
  $('#contact').click(function() {
    $('#contactForm').fadeToggle();
  })
  $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#contactForm");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.fadeOut();
    }
  });

});
</script>
```

Each time i choose a different file to upload the function loadfile() is called that is sending the input value that i have upload.My question is, how can i also pass the value of the button that has been pressed in the same function?

Can someone please help me?
Thanks in Regards

Comment: Can you post the code that launches the pop up form? Since this code is triggered on a button click, you should be able to store the value associated with the button and use it in your `loadFile` method.

Comment: I have updated the question with the pop up source code